# Read and show the name and age using pointers as function parameters

Tags: c, function, pointers

I want to write a function to read the name and the age of someone and a function to show them after using pointers as parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void read(char **name, int *age)
{
  printf("name: ");
  scanf("%s", *name);
  printf("age: ");
  scanf("%d", age);
}

void write(char *name, int age)
{
  printf("%s, %d\n", name, age);
}

int main(void)
{
  char *name;
  int age;
  read(&name, &age);
  write(name, age);
  free(name);
  return 0;
}
```

When I run this I get error message : `Process terminated with status -1073741819 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))`. Is it because I did not allocate any memory for `name`? Can you please explain me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot dereference a pointer until it points to a valid object. `name` is uninitialized. And you `free` it without allocating it which is wrong. So yes the error comes because you did not give any memory to `name`.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks! I forgot to do that and I could not understand what was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not allocating `name`, which is causing your application to crash, because `scanf` is probably causing an access violation by trying to write memory outside the application space.

You will need to either `malloc` some space:

```
char *name = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 256);
```

Or allocate some space on the stack (and remove the call to `free(name)` at the end):

```
char name[256];
```

Comment: Thanks! As someone else also pointed out, I forgot to allocate the memory.